# Binary stream upload through NGINX blocks all other POST requests to Node.js app

Tags: node.js, nginx

I'm running an application which accepts large file uploads, but also should allow the user to make other POST requests to the same app while the upload is it progress.

The app is running on node.js, with the upload being handled by formidable and s3stream to directly stream the binary content to S3 without using disk space on the server.

It seems like this is an NGINX configuration issue, as everything else works just fine locally.

My current NGINX config looks like this:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    server_name upload.app.io;
    underscores_in_headers on;

    location / {
        proxy_request_buffering off;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/ca-bundle.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/server.key;
}
```

So why is it that NGINX blocks any parallel POST requests while the upload is in progress, and how do I overcome this problem?

To clarify, NGINX does not throw an error, but rather hangs the requests until it times out.

Greatly appreciate any help with this.

Comment: Example URLs of both cases please

Comment: How do you know it's not Node hanging on the large upload? This is exactly the sort of thing that can happen with the single threaded model node is based on.

Comment: @BazzaDP I/O is non-blocking in Node.

Comment: Does the issue also happen with HTTPS instead of HTTP/2? I assume that by _"works just fine locally"_ you mean uploading directly to the Node server, without NGINX in front of it?

Answer (score 0):

I've since figured out one approach to handling the problem. It may not be the best practice but it works for what I need.

I'm now using two separate location blocks to handle the requests. One for file uploads, and another one for everything else. This way, I'm able to using the /upload block without buffering directly streamed to S3 via the app, and have the / block handle all other requests normally with buffers.

Here's the config:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    server_name upload.app.io;
    underscores_in_headers on;

    location /upload {
        client_max_body_size 0;
        proxy_request_buffering off;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/ca-bundle.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/server.key;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

client_max_body_size 10m;[enter link description here](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html)

Comment: How would that help?